# Must a WP landing page be in HTML or PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been asked to create a landing page for a client's WP site. I don't have much experience with WP and wondering if the page should be an HTML or PHP file? I have a CSS and JS file too. Any advice would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The short answer is that it is a PHP file that is the main initiator, but why not create the landing page using the WordPress admin area?  Coding it out sort of defeats the purpose of a CMS unless you have some extreme customizing to do.

Comment: If the plan is to just put that in front of the whole thing without using any WP functionality, then it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was just asked to create the landing page and send them the files and that they have a developer who would include it on their site

Comment: No functionality aside from a form

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the WordPress Codex on [how to make custom themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development). You could edit an existing theme although this isn't advised as you'll lose your changes when you update it.

The landing page must be saved as a PHP file. WordPress will automatically include the right file depending on the page that is requested. The most straightforward way to do this is create a file called `template-landing-page.php` and on the very first line of the file, paste this in:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Landing Page */ ?>
```

Then add your landing page content into that file. When you're done, go to the dashboard and edit/create a new page. Look for the Page Attributes meta box on the right hand side and select the Landing Page template. Save the page.

Then you have a new landing page!